# Comparing elements in Matlab and plotting

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I got 2 files that contain numbers. One number I use to calculate the max compression of a bone while the other number is the compression that is on the bone. If the second number is higher than the max compression I want to plot the dot in red, if it is less then it should be green.
My problem is that all my dots come out as red even though majority of the should be green. I have tried to debug it by printing out the H and C vector and there are like 100 numbers that should be red and the rest green. Any help or hints are appreciated.

This is my code

```
p=VarName5;
c=VarName7*2.5; %%The compression that is on the bone
if p<0.317;
  H=10500*p.^1.88; %%Calculate max compression the bone handles
else 
  H=114*p.^1.72; %%Calculate max compression the bone handles
end
if(c < H) %% if the compression on the bone is smaller then max compression
  plot(p,c,'+G') %% plot using green+
  hold on
else
  plot(p,c,'+R')  %if the compression is higher than max compression use red+
end
hold off
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a logical vector where all elements larger than the max values are 1, and all others are 0:

```
ind = c > H;
plot(p(ind),c(ind),'+R')
hold on
plot(p(~ind),c(~ind),'+G')
```

You may then plot them separately.

To illustrate with some random data:

```
c = repmat([1:6 7:-1:1],1,2);  %// The compression
H = rand(1,numel(c))*8; %// The compression the bone handles (in this case: random)
p = 1:numel(c);

ind = c > H;  %// Index of elements where the bone is compressed more than it handles.
plot(p(ind),c(ind),'+R')
hold on
plot(p(~ind),c(~ind),'+G')
```

[image]

I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to implement it into your code.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Did not know I could use plot like this.